SendMessageAsync and CompleteMessageAsync in the Same AzureFunction?. error Transaction hasn't been declared yet, or has already been dischargeding
when message received in Azure Service bus Topic, My Azure function gets triggered, it will send one new message to another Queue and complete the current message so that it should not trigger again. but in the below code, SendMessageAsync completing fine but when the CompleteMessageAsync calls getting "Transaction hasn't been declared yet, or has already been discharged" exception: Required help to fix this
public class Function1
 {
     [FunctionName("Function1")]
     //public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusTopicName%", "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
    // public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusTopicName%", "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)

       public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusTopicName%", "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString",IsSessionsEnabled =true)]
           ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
     {
         string serviceBusConnectionstring = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString");
         string topicName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusTopicName");
         string subscriptionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusSubscriptionName");
         string aiTopicName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusAITopicName");
         string aiTopicSubscriptionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusAISubscriptionName");
         string zendeskUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ZendeskURL");
         string userKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserKey");
         var requestKey = 1;
         var threadKey = 1;
         Console.WriteLine($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {message}");
         ServiceBusClientOptions options = new() { EnableCrossEntityTransactions = true };
         await using var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConnectionstring, options);
         ServiceBusSender sender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(aiTopicName);

         string jsonString = $@"{{""thread_key"": {threadKey}, ""request_key"": {requestKey}}}";
         Console.WriteLine(jsonString);  // Create a message and send it to the Service Bus queue
         try
         {

             ServiceBusMessage msg = new ServiceBusMessage(jsonString)
         {
             SessionId = threadKey.ToString()
         };
         using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
         { 
         **await sender.SendMessageAsync(msg);**
         Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: SendMessageAsync completed");
         **await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);**
         Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: CompleteMessageAsync completed");
         scope.Complete();
         }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             string errorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
             Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: Exception: {Message}- error log");
             Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: Exception: {Message}", errorMessage);

             if (ex.InnerException != null)
             {
                 errorMessage += " | Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
             }
             Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: Exception: {Message}", errorMessage);
             // Handle Service Bus message retries or deferral
            /* if (messageActions != null)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     // Option 1: Abandon the message so it can be retried
                     await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
                 }
                 catch (Exception abandonEx)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor:Failed to abandon message: {Message}", abandonEx.Message);
                 }
             }*/
         }
     }
 }


The receiver and the sender have to be created using the same ServiceBusClient instance for a transaction to work. But in your code they are created from different clients and therefore don't share the same connection object. The receiver is created by the Functions while the sender by your code.
In the past, it was possible to inject the MessageReceiver that Functions SDK would use to receive a message, and construct a MessageSender using MessageReceiver's connection object. Here is what it used to look like using In-Process SDK.
Since then, the ASB SDK has changed. For the new SDK you could inject ServiceBusClient and use it to create the sender, following the same pattern described in my blog.
But be aware that  support for Functions In-Process SDK will end on November 10, 2026 as it's replaced by the Isolated Worker SDK.
